# Error: Driver cannot be resolved to a variable- selenium java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get accustomed to using Selenium for automated testing.  So far I've successfully completed all aspects of this test case except for the final step which is to check if alert is present (transaction confirmation received)

I tried to use a boolean to execute this function, but i keep getting this same error : Driver cannot be resolved to a variable.

Any suggestions?

```
package com.scotia.test;      

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ScotiaTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/theone/Downloads/chromedriver-new");           

        // Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();                      

        //Login using Username and Password
        driver.get("https://LEAP:Password10@apps.scotiabank.com/LEAP_Prototype/desktop/html/Chile_index.html#"); 

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Find Proximity Serie A link and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#investing_tab tr:nth-child(7) a.acct-name")).click();

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000); 

        //Find New Funds Button and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pad-top-10.txt-right .btn.action-btn")).click();

         //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Select Field Rescue investment and choose Rescue
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mf_action")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Inversión");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Select Field Current account and choose current account
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selaccount_drpdown")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Cuenta Corriente *** 0002 USD 10.000,00");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Select Field Fund Type and choose medium term
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("term")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Mediano Plazo");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Select Field Mutual Fund Name and choose Proximity Series A
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("typefund")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Proximidad Serie A");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Select Field Fund account Name and choose 001
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sub_accnt")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("001");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Select Field Rode and type 222
        driver.findElement(By.id("amount_field")).sendKeys("222");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Find to Accept Button and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Find to Confirm Button and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Print a Log In message to the screen

         //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }       

    public boolean isAlertPresent(){ 
        try{ 
            Alert a = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            if(a!=null){
                System.out.println("Alert is present");
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
                return true;
            }else{
                throw new Throwable();
            }
        } 
        catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Alert isn't present!!");
            return false; 
        }   

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(2000);        
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the actual code you are using? It has lots of problems: isAlertPresent() is not called, you use driver there, but it's not a field of the class, etc. (You got "Error: Driver cannot be resolved to a variable" because of this)
I modified it to be runnable (incorporated `isAlertPresent()` into `main()`), and got that green "alert" at the end. Did you mean that? If yes, it's not an alert, it's just a div, so instead of this:

```
Alert a = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

write something like this:

```
WebElement div = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("success-msg")));
```

If this is not the case, please edit your question with the alert you meant.
[image]